# What's up with 'Microsoft' as the default company and copyright on project settings in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, copyright-display

I noticed that when I enter the Assembly Information dialog, for a project created in

- Visual Studio 2010
- Visual C#/Basic 2010 Express

...the company and copyright fields default to Microsoft (...). How ***odd*** is that? If a developer were to forget this, Microsoft practically brands software made by others as their own.

Is there some way I can change the defaults for this?

Comment: It's just part of the template, not a Microsoft conspiracy to own your software.

Comment: Yes, but it's new since VS 2005, so it's downright a little stupid.

Comment: The alternative is defaulting to YourCompany, but then the programmer would look even sillier if s/he forgot to change it.

Comment: The license that you clicked through when you installed VS *requires* you to claim copyright on your software.  The name is just a place holder, making it obvious that a company name should be entered there.  Nobody is likely to understand what "Contoso" means.

Comment: Btw, I've seen several DLLs that had "Enter your company name here" in their copyright notice.  Hehe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is part of the default templates.  You can add your own, or replace the defaults.  For details, see [Visual Studio Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) - in particular, [Creating Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247120.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any speculative comments as to why it's MS by default? :)

Comment: @Cecil: They made the templates that are there by default.  ;)  Personally, I think they should make the defaults "Unknown" or something, not Microsoft, but I think they wanted to include *something* so people would know to put that in place.